What would it look like if space had a boundary
Space in the universe as far as we know either extends infinitely in all directions, or it is finite but one edge of the finite space is connected to the other end. Like the 2d plane on 3D torus because of that cosmological principle that states that the universe on a large enough scale is more or less the same in all directions.
And having a boundary violates that because that means the edge is different from everywhere else.
The question I am trying to ask is really multiple ones:
If boundary is basically a black hole, anything that passes through this black wall cannot go back into the bounded space, would this black wall be basically pitch black?
Can something “orbit around the perimeter of this black wall.
And if you stick your hand into the black wall, I imagine it would not feel resistance, but it would when trying to pull it back?
If the boundary is a “white wall” where it takes an infinite amount of time to approach the edge. Assuming it emits no particles itself, would photons become “stuck” in place, constantly moving towards a boundary it can never reach thus, the light is never seen. Or would the light be reflected off the boundary working like a mirror. Would this not illuminate the entirety of the enclosed space?
Would you feel resistance if you try to touch the white wall, would if there is no resistance would just you moving forward but never able to reach the white wall?
Thank you.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Welcome Synthia. Excuse the bot's abruptness. We do ask that you edit down to a single focused question, one per post. Additional questions can be posted in their own threads with a link to this one if you like. Perhaps ask about one alternative here, then the opposite alternative in another question, that way you get thorough treatments of each question for you to then make a choice in your writing.

I agree with @Escapeddentalpatient.. We're lenient with new users, but you're asking a lot of questions and most of them are completely speculative. There's no science respecting a boundary to any universe. Worse, white holes are mathematical hypotheses, not scientific reality. That leaves you making assumptions. If you want the boundary to be a giant spherical (so to speak) black hole, then of course it would "look like" a black hole. Why wouldn't that be a sufficient answer?


If boundary is basically a black hole, anything that passes through this black wall cannot go back into the bounded space, would this black wall be basically pitch black?

As described, yes.

And if you stick your hand into the black wall, I imagine it would not feel resistance, but it would when trying to pull it back?

Since your "black hole" wall doesn't sound like it has any gravitational pull, yes.

If the boundary is a “white wall” where it takes an infinite amount of time to approach the edge. Assuming it emits no particles itself, would photons become “stuck” in place, constantly moving towards a boundary it can never reach thus, the light is never seen. Or would the light be reflected off the boundary working like a mirror.

Those two options are completely contradictory. Either the boundary is a reflective mirror, or it's some strange spatial distortion that takes an infinite amount of time to reach. The latter option would be literally indistinguishable from just having no border at all.

A black hole would not let light escape. A white hole would. In fact it repels photons in theory. If gravity is nothing more than the result of the second law of thermodynamics, anti gravity violates it and therefore white holes are impossible. At least on the macroscopic level. When we get to the subatomic level, who knows. But it's possible that the universe is a hologram and therefore the boundary is something hard to imagine. Of course boundary is a strange term. You don't really have a boundary. Also the universe is not the same in all directions. There are all kinds of structures. They sort of happened after the big bang and were inflated. You pretty much can't observe large parts of the universe because of the rate it which it expands.

"Also the universe is not the same in all directions." This is definitely not true. A very important astronomical observation is that the visible universe is homogeneous at large scales
